# Marked cells can be divided into $1\times 2$ rectangle

Tags: combinatorics

A rectangle is colored black/white in checkerboard pattern. Some cells are marked with a cross. If any cell is marked with a cross, then so are all cells that are lower or to the left (or both) to that cell. Suppose that the number of marked black cells is equal to the number of marked white cells. Prove that the marked cells can be divided into $1\times 2$ rectangles.

When we consider any marked cell, and the rectangle with it as the upper-right corner, then if at least one of the two side lengths is even, we can divide it into $1\times 2$ rectangles. If both side lengths are odd, we clearly can't, and have to combine it with some other cells.